# Tikz Polar Fill to Origin

Tags: tikz-pgf, polarplot

I'm trying to shade under a polar graph.  I'm using this code:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[fill=gray] plot[domain=pi/8:pi/4] (xy polar cs:angle=\x r,radius= {3*cos(pi/8 r)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The result doesn't fill all the way to the origin as it should.  I'm getting this:

[image]

How do I make it shade all the way to the origin?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I completed the code.

Comment: Your code doesn't produce the picture in your question! The idea of [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) is to help people help you. Asking us to recreate your picture (almost) from scratch seems a little pointless...

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[fill=gray] (0,0) -- ++({pi/8}:{3*cos(pi/8 r)}) plot[domain=pi/8:pi/4] (xy polar cs:angle=\x r,radius= {3*cos(pi/8 r)})--(0,0)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]