# PGFPlots: Background color for polar plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, polarplot

I would like to draw a so called "skyplot" in PGFPlots. Skyplots display satellites with their positions over the visible sky. In addition, I would like to draw a background for some specific disturbances. Eventually it should look like this:
[image: Example of a skyplot with background]

Creating the coordinate system and placing the satellites worked like a charm with PGFPlots' polaraxis:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\newlength\figureheight
\newlength\figurewidth

\definecolor{GPS_Color}{RGB}{0, 187, 0}
\definecolor{GLO_Color}{RGB}{196, 163, 0}
\definecolor{GAL_Color}{RGB}{0, 140, 190}
\definecolor{BDS_Color}{RGB}{196, 0, 0}

\begin{document}
\scriptsize
\setlength\figureheight{\textwidth}
\setlength\figurewidth{\textwidth}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}[
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
rotate=-90,
axis lines*=none,
axis line style = {draw=transparent,line width=0.0001pt},
x dir=reverse,
xticklabel style={anchor=-\tick-90},
xtick={0,30,60,90,120,150,180,210,240,270,300,330},
xticklabels={N,30,60,E,120,150,S,210,240,W,300,330},
ymin=0,
ymax=90,
ytick={0,10,...,90},
yticklabels=\empty
]
\node [anchor=center,draw,circle,black,fill=GPS_Color,minimum size=3ex,inner sep=0pt] at (axis cs:30,90-80) {\tiny{G30}};
\node [anchor=center,draw,circle,black,fill=GAL_Color,minimum size=3ex,inner sep=0pt] at (axis cs:280,90-10) {\tiny{E01}};
\node [anchor=center,draw,circle,black,fill=GLO_Color,minimum size=3ex,inner sep=0pt] at (axis cs:150,90-89) {\tiny{R13}};
\node [anchor=center,draw,circle,black,fill=BDS_Color,minimum size=3ex,inner sep=0pt] at (axis cs:210,90-35) {\tiny{C14}};
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This results in this diagram:

[image: Output of the given code]

However, I cannot find a way to display the background colors. I developed an application which calculates the satellite positions and the background, this is how I created the figure. Now I would like to extend this application to generate tikz/pgf code for publication in TeX. The color data for the background is available as some kind of image, so an rectangular array of pixels with specific colors. However, as this data relies on a cartesian axis, I cannot plot it directly in the polaraxis environment.

How can I create such a colored background in PGFPlots polaraxis environment?

Thank you very much.

Comment: +1: Nice MWE and cool use case :)

Comment: Just as an inspiration, maybe these Q+As help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/454970/ or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162889.

Comment: Could you show us the color data array? - First: I think we have to transform the cartesian color coordinate (of the array) into polar cordinates. Secondly: Fill background color with the specific color of the array. Maybe helpful: [Creating a Polar Grid with Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169624/creating-a-polar-grid-with-tikz), [Polar plot fill segmented area](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304588/pgfplots-polar-plot-extrema-of-values-and-fill-segmented-area), [Tikz Polar Fill to Origin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239692/tikz-polar-fill-to-origin)

Comment: Hi @BigMick, welcome! Do you need to remap the color data in your matrix or you need just displaying it in the background and clipping to the circle? I suspect that preparing the color data in the app would be easier...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want to add a background image (generated with your other program), and you have the image available in whatever format, you can add it on the background. Notice that I used `scale only axis` to force the dimension of the polar plot to exactly fit the requested ones.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\newlength\figureheight
\newlength\figurewidth

\definecolor{GPS_Color}{RGB}{0, 187, 0}
\definecolor{GLO_Color}{RGB}{196, 163, 0}
\definecolor{GAL_Color}{RGB}{0, 140, 190}
\definecolor{BDS_Color}{RGB}{196, 0, 0}

\begin{document}
\scriptsize
\setlength\figureheight{\textwidth}
\setlength\figurewidth{\textwidth}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt,  opacity=0.3,
            ] at (0,0)
            {\includegraphics[width=\figurewidth,
                height=\figureheight]{example-image-a}
            };
    \end{scope}
    \begin{polaraxis}[
        width=\figurewidth,
        height=\figureheight,
        rotate=-90,
        axis lines*=none,
        axis line style = {draw=transparent,line width=0.0001pt},
        x dir=reverse,
        xticklabel style={anchor=-\tick-90},
        xtick={0,30,60,90,120,150,180,210,240,270,300,330},
        xticklabels={N,30,60,E,120,150,S,210,240,W,300,330},
        ymin=0,
        ymax=90,
        ytick={0,10,...,90},
        yticklabels=\empty,
        scale only axis,
        ]
        \node [anchor=center,draw,circle,black,fill=GPS_Color,minimum size=3ex,inner sep=0pt] at (axis cs:30,90-80) {\tiny{G30}};
        \node [anchor=center,draw,circle,black,fill=GAL_Color,minimum size=3ex,inner sep=0pt] at (axis cs:280,90-10) {\tiny{E01}};
        \node [anchor=center,draw,circle,black,fill=GLO_Color,minimum size=3ex,inner sep=0pt] at (axis cs:150,90-89) {\tiny{R13}};
        \node [anchor=center,draw,circle,black,fill=BDS_Color,minimum size=3ex,inner sep=0pt] at (axis cs:210,90-35) {\tiny{C14}};
    \end{polaraxis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output from the above snippet]

The OP posted the final result:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I extended my application to output the background gradient as an image and generate LaTeX/PGFPlots code which can be compiled with LaTeX. Thank you all very much for your answers!

Comment: An example result (rendered as PDF by LuaLaTeX, converted into a JPG image) can be found here: https://imgur.com/a/jRGX1uR

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, happy to help! can I embed a link to your image to the answer?

Comment: Sure, of course! Thank you very much for that hint!

Answer (score 7):

At the conceptual level a bit similar to [koleygr's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/458164/121799) but no hardcoded distances and a finer color transition. (**EDIT**: Use color picker to reproduce your color, big big thanks to AndrèC!)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\newlength\figureheight
\newlength\figurewidth

\definecolor{GPS_Color}{RGB}{0, 187, 0}
\definecolor{GLO_Color}{RGB}{196, 163, 0}
\definecolor{GAL_Color}{RGB}{0, 140, 190}
\definecolor{BDS_Color}{RGB}{196, 0, 0}

\definecolor{LEFT_Color}{RGB}{152, 205, 225}
\definecolor{RIGHT_Color}{RGB}{242, 204, 48}
\begin{document}
\scriptsize
\setlength\figureheight{\textwidth}
\setlength\figurewidth{\textwidth}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}[
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
rotate=-90,
axis lines*=none,
axis line style = {draw=transparent,line width=0.0001pt},
x dir=reverse,
xticklabel style={anchor=-\tick-90},
xtick={0,30,60,90,120,150,180,210,240,270,300,330},
xticklabels={N,30,60,E,120,150,S,210,240,W,300,330},
ymin=0,
ymax=90,
ytick={0,10,...,90},
yticklabels=\empty
]
\node [anchor=center,draw,circle,black,fill=GPS_Color,minimum size=3ex,inner sep=0pt] at (axis cs:30,90-80) {\tiny{G30}};
\node [anchor=center,draw,circle,black,fill=GAL_Color,minimum size=3ex,inner sep=0pt] at (axis cs:280,90-10) {\tiny{E01}};
\node [anchor=center,draw,circle,black,fill=GLO_Color,minimum size=3ex,inner sep=0pt] at (axis cs:150,90-89) {\tiny{R13}};
\node [anchor=center,draw,circle,black,fill=BDS_Color,minimum size=3ex,inner sep=0pt] at (axis cs:210,90-35) {\tiny{C14}};
\coordinate (c) at (axis cs:0,0);
\coordinate (aux) at (axis cs:0,90);
\coordinate (t) at (axis cs:15,90);
\coordinate (m) at (axis cs:0,40);
\coordinate (b) at (axis cs:200,90);
\end{polaraxis}
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\clip let \p1=($(aux)-(c)$),\n1={veclen(\y1,\x1)} in (c) circle (\n1);
\fill[LEFT_Color] let \p1=($(aux)-(c)$) in (c) circle (\y1);
\path let \p1=($([xshift=-6,yshift=10]t)-(c)$),\n1={1.025*veclen(\y1,\x1)} in \pgfextra{\xdef\myrad{\n1}};
\foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Y using {int(50+\X)}] in {-50,...,50}
{\fill[RIGHT_Color!\Y!LEFT_Color] ([xshift=0.2*\X,yshift=10]t) to[out=-120,in=70]
([xshift=0.2*\X]m) to[out=-110,in=90] ([xshift=0.2*\X,yshift=-10]b) arc(250:435:\myrad);}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Even if one zooms in a lot, one has still a rather smooth transition.

[image]

Comment: Under linux, there are pipette tools that allow you to find the colors displayed on the screen: http://gcolor2.sourceforge.net/ under Windows and Mac : http://annystudio.com/software/colorpicker/

Comment: Both are free of charge.

Comment: @AndréC Thanks a lot! That's a really useful toot!

Answer (score 6):

This is a way that can be adjusted in colors and the "blur" by you:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\newlength\figureheight
\newlength\figurewidth

\definecolor{GPS_Color}{RGB}{0, 187, 0}
\definecolor{GLO_Color}{RGB}{196, 163, 0}
\definecolor{GAL_Color}{RGB}{0, 140, 190}
\definecolor{BDS_Color}{RGB}{196, 0, 0}
\definecolor{SKY_Color}{RGB}{0, 157, 210}


\begin{document}
\scriptsize
\setlength\figureheight{\textwidth}
\setlength\figurewidth{\textwidth}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}[
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
rotate=-90,
axis lines*=none,
axis line style = {draw=transparent,line width=0.0001pt},
x dir=reverse,
xticklabel style={anchor=-\tick-90},
xtick={0,30,60,90,120,150,180,210,240,270,300,330},
xticklabels={N,30,60,E,120,150,S,210,240,W,300,330},
ymin=0,
ymax=90,
ytick={0,10,...,90},
yticklabels=\empty
]
\end{polaraxis}
\clip (5.27,5.27) circle (5.25);
\fill[SKY_Color] (5.3,5.3) circle (5.3);
\fill[orange!50!yellow,rotate=-30, shift={(70:10)}] (1.6,-2) ellipse (4 and 6);
\draw[yellow,opacity=0.4,line width=0.2cm,rotate=-30,shift={(70:10)}] (1.6,-2) ellipse (4.05 and 6.05);
\draw[yellow,opacity=0.2,line width=0.2cm,rotate=-30,shift={(70:10)}] (1.6,-2) ellipse (4.2 and 6.2);
\draw[yellow,opacity=0.1,line width=0.2cm,rotate=-30,shift={(70:10)}] (1.6,-2) ellipse (4.3 and 6.3);
\begin{scope}
\begin{polaraxis}[
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
rotate=-90,
axis lines*=none,
axis line style = {draw=transparent,line width=0.0001pt},
x dir=reverse,
xticklabel style={anchor=-\tick-90},
xtick={0,30,60,90,120,150,180,210,240,270,300,330},
xticklabels={N,30,60,E,120,150,S,210,240,W,300,330},
ymin=0,
ymax=90,
ytick={0,10,...,90},
yticklabels=\empty
]
\node [anchor=center,draw,circle,black,fill=GPS_Color,minimum size=3ex,inner sep=0pt] at (axis cs:30,90-80) {\tiny{G30}};
\node [anchor=center,draw,circle,black,fill=GAL_Color,minimum size=3ex,inner sep=0pt] at (axis cs:280,90-10) {\tiny{E01}};
\node [anchor=center,draw,circle,black,fill=GLO_Color,minimum size=3ex,inner sep=0pt] at (axis cs:150,90-89) {\tiny{R13}};
\node [anchor=center,draw,circle,black,fill=BDS_Color,minimum size=3ex,inner sep=0pt] at (axis cs:210,90-35) {\tiny{C14}};
\end{polaraxis}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

PS: I used a filled circle with your center, an ellipse with an appropriate color, center/rotation, some ellipses for "bluring" and cliped the image with a circle using your center and an appropriate radius.